# ng-repeat elements are removed from the DOM after a moment rather than immediately

Tags: angularjs

I have this instagram feed page which shows liked media from a specific user, the results are limited to 6:

```
 <li ng-repeat="p in pics | limitTo: 6">
   <a href="{{p.link}}" target="_blank">
     <img ng-src="{{p.images.standard_resolution.url}}" />
   </a>
 </li>
 <button ng-click="shuffle()">Shuffle</button>
```

I also added a shuffle button which when you click picks 6 pictures at random from the total amount of pictures in the JSON. However when you click it shows them all for a second. Is there a way to stop this from happening?

**JS**

```
app.controller('ShowImages', function($scope, InstagramAPI){
    $scope.layout = 'grid';
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.pics = [];
    $scope.shuffle = function() {
        $scope.pics.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() });
    };
    InstagramAPI.fetchPhotos(function(data){
        $scope.pics = data;
        console.log("length is "+data.length)
    });
});
```

You can see it here:

http://alexanderlloyd.info/Angular-Instafeed-master/

Comment: Do you have an transition style applied for repeated elements leaving the dom? (.ng-leave)

Comment: I'd *guess* that using `p in pics | limitTo: 6 track by $index` would fix the problem.

Comment: well I add a class which has an opacity transition when there are more than 0 pics like so <div  class="container" data-ng-class="{ 'loaded': pics.length > 0 }">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is as expected because your elements are styled with `.ng-leave` so that they fade out when leaving the DOM. You just need to remove that style from those elements altogether, or if needed, conditionally apply/remove the transition so that it is not affecting the elements in the state you're currently dealing with.

This style is the problem:

```
.page .ng-leave {
  -webkit-animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
  -moz-animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
  animation: fadeOut 0.6s both ease-in;
}
```

Any element inside of `.page` that gets the class `.ng-leave` is going to be animated out. Perhaps you meant that to be `.page.ng-leave` so that it would only apply to `.page`? I removed that style and tried the shuffle and the leaving elements were immediately removed as you desire.

Comment: thanks, you're right ;) just so I know where exactly is the ng-leave and ng-enter classes added , ie which tag?